# Generate Combinations for a set of Numbers

Tags: c#, for-loop, numbers, combinations

In C#, I want to generate combinations for `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}` in 5 digits. So, I want to get an output of 11111,11112, etc up to 99999.

When I searched I didn't get anything that could work when I threw it into a console application.

Everything always got an error with Combinations...

Comment: In your trivial example, you don't need to generate combinations at all, you can just hold 00000 through 99999 in an array or count, as the case may be. Does your actual use case have varying inputs?

Comment: Are you looking to generate all the permutations of a list?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? If so you can choose it as an answer by clicking the checkmark under the voting widget for the answer

Answer (score 7):

do a for loop and count from 11111 to 99999:

```
for(int i = 11111; i<=99999; i++){
    var combination = i.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(combination);
}
```

or if you want 00001 to 99999

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 99999; i++)
{
    var combination = String.Format("{0:D5}", i);
    Console.WriteLine(combination);
}
```

Comment: Note that if your set of values to choose from isn't exactly the digits 0...9 you can use the overload of `Convert.ToString()` that takes a base of the number of items you have to choose from.  Then you just need to change the end condition of the `for` loop to x ^ y where X is the number of items you choose from and Y is the number of digits in the result.

Comment: Thanks! Now, how can I grab each individual value generated, one by one, and use it for an input?

Comment: each individual value is in the `combination` variable

Answer (score 2):

Simply counting from 0 to 99999 will produce all combinations (and you really should start with 00000 if you want all combinations)

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a way to combine numbers, not specifically to get a sequence, you can do a linq query for it.

```
         var bob = new [] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
         var greg =
             from a in bob
             from b in bob
             from c in bob
             from d in bob
             from e in bob
             select string.Concat(a, b, c, d, e);
```

Comment: That only works if you know the number of items in the array at compile time.

Comment: No.  The array can be built dynamically and a Cartesian product can be built at any time.  You may be thinking that it only works for 5 characters compile, which would be true.

Comment: Correct, I meant to say that this only works for a fixed size of the output, not a fixed size of the input array.  It's still often something that needs to not be fixed though.